# Represent data from json file in rating stars without jquery!! pure javaScript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, css

I am trying to load the data from my JSON file using javaScript and i need to represent the hotel2show.rating in form of stars, just represent them dependig on the value from 'hotels.json'

Here is my JavaScript

```
function getHotels(i){

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
                hotel=JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                var hotel2show = hotel.hotels[i];
                document.getElementById("img-container").innerHTML = 
                "<img src='"+hotel2show.imgUrl+"'>"+
         "<p id='name'><strong>"+ hotel2show.name +"</strong></p>" +"<br/>" + "<p id='rating'><strong>"+ hotel2show.rating +"</strong></p>" +"<br/>" + "<br/>" +"<p id='price'><strong>"+ '&pound;' +hotel2show.price +
             "</strong></p>" + "<p id='text'><strong>"+ 'Total hotel stay' +"</strong></p>";

        } else {
                alert("Ha existido un error con el servidor");

        }
    } 
};
xhr.open("GET",'hotels.json', true);
xhr.send();
```

and here is my html

```
<div class="container">
 <div id="lista">
  <ul> 
   <button onclick="getHotels(0)">Hotel Sunny Palms</button>
   <button onclick="getHotels(1)">Hotel Snowy Mountains</button>
   <button onclick="getHotels(2)">Hotel Windy Sails</button>
   <button onclick="getHotels(3)">Hotel Middle Of Nowhere</button>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="banner-section" id="img-container">
</div>
```

and my hotels.json

```
"hotels": [
    {
        "name": "Hotel Sunny Palms",
        "imgUrl": "imgs/sunny.jpg",
        "rating": 5,
        "price": 108.00
    },
    {
        "name": "Hotel Snowy Mountains",
        "imgUrl": "imgs/snowy.jpg",
        "rating": 4,
        "price": 120.00
    },
    {
        "name": "Hotel Windy Sails",
        "imgUrl": "imgs/windy.jpg",
        "rating": 3,
        "price": 110.00
    },
    {
        "name": "Hotel Middle of Nowhere",
        "imgUrl": "imgs/nowhere.jpg",
        "rating": 4,
        "price": 199.00
    }
]
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: *"without jquery!! only javascript"* jQuery is just a library, not a language; you're still using JavaScript when you use it. "Without jQuery (or another library)" means "with the DOM API."

Comment: I Know, but i should not use any library, not jquery, not bootstrap. only javaScript and css

Comment: The point being that "only JavaScript" is meaningless in the title of the question

Comment: true, sorry about that !!

Comment: appendString is a var we declared it here

var appendString = [];

then I misspelled it in case 2 and you copied it to case 3,4,5.  Also you should define a default case. [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you know how to parse out your ratings, right? If you are just displaying single star values (whole numbers), then you can just write out a class onto a span element where you would style it with CSS to change what the background image would be.

So, you could make it show 1-5 stars with 4 different images.

It's a solution; not the cleanest or most scalable, but it works for this situation.

So first off this is a nightmare.

Let's clean it up a bit?

```
var appendString = [];
appendString[0] =  "<img src='"+hotel2show.imgUrl+"'>";
appendString[1] = "<p id='name'><strong>"+ hotel2show.name +"</strong></p><br/>";
switch(hotel2show.rating):
case(1):
appendString[2] = "<p id='rating' class='rating-1'><strong>";
break;
case(2):
appendStirng[2] = "<p id='rating' class='rating-2><strong>";
break;
//etc 

appendString[3] = hotel2show.rating +"</strong></p>";
appendString[4] = "<br/><br/>";
appendString[5] = "<p id='price'><strong>'&pound;'" + hotel2show.price + "</strong></p>";
appendString[6] = "<p id='text'><strong>"+ 'Total hotel stay' +"</strong></p>";
document.getElementById("img-container").innerHTML = appendString.join(' ');
```

Note: the `switch` statement syntax may be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

For example..if you have UTF-8 charset then this should perhaps be fine. The key is [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) function by which you can construct your DOM as you wish.

```js
var hotels = [{
  "name": "Hotel Sunny Palms",
  "imgUrl": "imgs/sunny.jpg",
  "rating": 5,
  "price": 108.00
}, {
  "name": "Hotel Snowy Mountains",
  "imgUrl": "imgs/snowy.jpg",
  "rating": 4,
  "price": 120.00
}, {
  "name": "Hotel Windy Sails",
  "imgUrl": "imgs/windy.jpg",
  "rating": 3,
  "price": 110.00
}, {
  "name": "Hotel Middle of Nowhere",
  "imgUrl": "imgs/nowhere.jpg",
  "rating": 4,
  "price": 199.00
}];

buildRating(hotels);

function buildRating(data) {
  data.forEach(function(v) {
    createRatingElement(v.rating);
  });
}

function createRatingElement(numberOfStars) {
  var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    var span = document.createElement('span')
    span.innerHTML = (i <= numberOfStars ? '★' : '☆');
    span.className = (i <= numberOfStars ? 'high' : '');
    wrapper.appendChild(span);
  }
  document.getElementById('img-container').appendChild(wrapper);
}
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  color: black;
}
.high {
  color: rgb(217, 211, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-section" id="img-container">

</div>
```

Also, jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/md4708oq/

Comment: I like this answer,  clean and simple.

Answer (score 0):

> You will have to use AJAX calls to retrieve JSON data and then use pure javascript to parse the JSON data and use it to display your html accordingly. Let me know if this is what you are looking for i will help you out with the same.